# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert [navigation-outcome] of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I'm trying to us JSF composite component in my web application but I run the page and click on nav bar I had this error 
UPDATE

I change the `<m:link outcome="#{cc.attrs.caption}" value="#{cc.attrs.jsf}"   />` to  `<m:link outcome="#{cc.attrs.caption}" value="#{cc.attrs.jsf}"   />`
i get this message on link

V: This link is disabled because a navigation case could not be matched

XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:mnu="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/mnu">
    <h:head>
        <title>First Mobile JSF page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>  
        <style>
            #box1 {
                margin-left: 25%;
                margin-top: 55%;
                width: 50%;
                border-style: solid;

            }
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
        <div data-role="page" home="home">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Add Product</h1>
            </div> 
                <div data-role="content">
                    <p>Dummy page add Product</p>

                </div>


            <div data-role="footer" data-postion="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                     <ul>
                      <!--  <li><a href="/Info5059Case1/C1Control?jsf=V" data-ajax="false">Add Vendor</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="/Info5059Case1/C1Control?jsf=P" data-ajax="false">Add Product</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="/Info5059Case1/C1Control?jsf=O" data-ajax="false">Generator PO</a> </li>-->

                      <mnu:MenuItem caption="Add Vendor" jsf="V"/>
                      <mnu:MenuItem caption="Add Product" jsf="P"/>
                      <mnu:MenuItem caption="Add Product" jsf="O"/>
                     </ul>
                </div>            
            </div>  
        </div>
      </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**composite component**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
       xmlns:m="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <!-- INTERFACE -->
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="caption" required="true"/>
        <cc:attribute name="jsf" required="true"/>
    </cc:interface>

    <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
    <cc:implementation>
        <m:commandLink action="#{cc.attrs.jsf}" value="#{cc.attrs.caption}" />
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

```
An Error Occurred:

javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert V of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression

- Stack Trace

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert V of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert V of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:473)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:465)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert V of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:417)
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:77)
    ... 42 more


- Component Tree

<UIViewRoot id="j_id1" inView="true" locale="en_US" renderKitId="HTML_BASIC" rendered="true" transient="false" viewId="/AddProduct.xhtml"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><UIOutput id="j_idt2" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"><title>First Mobile JSF page</title> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"/> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"/> <style> #box1 { margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 55%; width: 50%; border-style: solid; } </style></UIOutput><UIOutput id="j_idt4" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"><HtmlForm enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="j_idt5" inView="true" prependId="true" rendered="true" submitted="true" transient="false"><div data-role="page" home="home"> <div data-role="header"> <h1>Add Product</h1> </div> <div data-role="content"> <p>Dummy page add Product</p> <!--name<h:inputText id="userName" value="#{sampleViewModel.name}" size="5"/> <h:commandButton id="something" value="doSomething" action="#{sampleViewModel.doSomething}"/>--> <div id="box1"><HtmlOutputText escape="false" id="j_idt7" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/></div> </div> <div data-role="footer" data-postion="fixed"> <div data-role="navbar"> <ul> <!-- <li><a href="/Info5059Case1/C1Control?jsf=V" data-ajax="false">Add Vendor</a> </li> <li><a href="/Info5059Case1/C1Control?jsf=P" data-ajax="false">Add Product</a> </li> <li><a href="/Info5059Case1/C1Control?jsf=O" data-ajax="false">Generator PO</a> </li>--><UINamingContainer id="j_idt12" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">javax.faces.component.COMPOSITE_FACET_NAME<UIPanel id="j_id6" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <!-- INTERFACE --><!-- IMPLEMENTATION --><HtmlCommandLink action="#{cc.attrs.jsf}" actionExpression="#{cc.attrs.jsf}" disabled="false" id="j_idt13" immediate="false" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/></html></UIPanel></UINamingContainer><UINamingContainer id="j_idt14" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">javax.faces.component.COMPOSITE_FACET_NAME<UIPanel id="j_id6" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <!-- INTERFACE --><!-- IMPLEMENTATION --><HtmlCommandLink action="#{cc.attrs.jsf}" actionExpression="#{cc.attrs.jsf}" disabled="false" id="j_idt13" immediate="false" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/></html></UIPanel></UINamingContainer><UINamingContainer id="j_idt15" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false">javax.faces.component.COMPOSITE_FACET_NAME<UIPanel id="j_id6" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <!-- INTERFACE --><!-- IMPLEMENTATION --><HtmlCommandLink action="#{cc.attrs.jsf}" actionExpression="#{cc.attrs.jsf}" disabled="false" id="j_idt13" immediate="false" inView="true" rendered="true" transient="false"/></html></UIPanel></UINamingContainer></ul> </div> </div> </div></HtmlForm></UIOutput></html></UIViewRoot>
- Scoped Variables


Request Parameters


Name

Value


j_idt5 j_idt5 
j_idt5:j_idt12:j_idt13 j_idt5:j_idt12:j_idt13 

View Attributes


Name

Value


None 

Request Attributes


Name

Value


None 

Flash Attributes


Name

Value


None 

Session Attributes


Name

Value


None 

Application Attributes


Name

Value


csfcff [ ]
```

Comment: Don't work with composites, but the error is saying JSF expects a method instead of "V" in your `jsf` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The `<h:commandLink>` is intented as form submit link, not as page navigation link.

Use `<h:link>` instead.

So, replace

```
<m:commandLink action="#{cc.attrs.jsf}" value="#{cc.attrs.caption}" />
```

by

```
<m:link outcome="#{cc.attrs.jsf}" value="#{cc.attrs.caption}" />
```

*(and, to be respectful and friendly towards readers of your code, rename `xmlns:m` to `xmlns:h`)*

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/4317723#4317723)

Comment: Apparently you actually don't have a `/V.xhtml` file. What exactly are you trying to do then? What exactly do those `V`, `P` and `O` represent? Navigation outcomes, right? If not, then you're approaching this plain wrong and you'd have faced exactly the same problem when not using a composite component.

Comment: I am trying to pass the value using QueryString to navigate bwtween pages

Comment: Sorry, this statement isn't making any sense. Please elaborate the concrete functional requirement in detail in clear terms. Your attempt would have failed as hard when not using a composite component. So pointing your accusing finger to composite component is a completely wrong way of thinking in first place.